# If you travel faster than a neutrino, will it appear right-handed?

Tags: reference-frames, neutrinos, chirality, helicity

Since neutrinos have mass they move slower than lightspeed. So it is possible to move faster. And if you move faster than the relative direction of the neutrino velocity is backwards. But the spin stays the same. And opposite directions for speed and spin would mean that the neutrino appears right-handed. Is this correct? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Their *helicity* will reverse, yes

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/150263, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/290074

Comment: @NiharKarve, thanks for pointing to the difference between helicity and chirality. That answers my question.